# How to set foreground attribute to other non FrameLayout view

Tags: android, view, drawable, android-view, android-framelayout

I would like to know how to apply or emulate foreground effect in a view different from FrameLayout, as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

This is what I have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/row_background"
    android:foreground="@drawable/foreground_row">

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

And I want something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/row_background"
        app:foreground="@drawable/foreground_row">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 21):

The idea is to surround your layout with a FrameLayout, and set the selector and the onClick event to this layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/selectableItem"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:foreground="@drawable/foreground_row"
    >

   <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/row_background">

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

You can find a full explanation at my blog:

http://antonioleiva.com/unveiling-bandhook-foreground-any-layout/

Or you can extend rhis `FRelativeLayout` https://gist.github.com/shakalaca/6199283

Comment: If you want to use the `foreground` attribute just **to add a ripple over an `ImageView`**, there's a [simpler and better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61202414/1276306) than wrapping it in a `<FrameLayout>` or subclassing it.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [ForegroundView](https://github.com/baole/ForegroundView) library with Gradle integration. It supports following views

- ForegroundImageView
- ForegroundButton
- ForegroundTextView
- ForegroundImageButton
- ForegroundEditText
- ForegroundWebView
- ForegroundLinearLayout
- ForegroundRelativeLayout
- ForegroundGridLayout
- ForegroundGridView
- ForegroundHorizontalScrollView
- ForegroundListView
- ForegroundScrollViewForegroundImageView

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible implementation, one which also supports checking a layout.

A nearly identical solution can be applied to any layout view you wish (only the CTOR is different).

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;
    private static final String TAG = CheckableLinearLayout.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked };
    private Drawable mForeground;

    public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        final TypedArray a = context
                .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CheckableLinearLayout, defStyle, 0);
        setForegroundEx(a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CheckableLinearLayout_foreground));
        a.recycle();
    }

    public void setForegroundEx(final Drawable drawable) {
        this.mForeground = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        final Drawable drawable = getBackground();
        boolean needRedraw = false;
        final int[] myDrawableState = getDrawableState();
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setState(myDrawableState);
            needRedraw = true;
        }
        if (mForeground != null) {
            mForeground.setState(myDrawableState);
            needRedraw = true;
        }
        if (needRedraw)
            invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int width, final int height, final int oldwidth, final int oldheight) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
        if (mForeground != null)
            mForeground.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        if (mForeground != null)
            mForeground.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(final boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
        //TODO think if you wish to also check inner views, maybe even recursively
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        // Force our ancestor class to save its state
        final Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        final SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
        savedState.checked = isChecked();
        return savedState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(final Parcelable state) {
        final SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
        setChecked(savedState.checked);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent e) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && //
                e.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && //
                mForeground != null)
            mForeground.setHotspot(e.getX(), e.getY());
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    // /////////////
    // SavedState //
    // /////////////

    private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        boolean checked;

        SavedState(final Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(final Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            checked = (Boolean) in.readValue(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, final int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeValue(checked);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return TAG + ".SavedState{" + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this)) + " checked=" + checked
                    + "}";
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(final Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(final int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**attr.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="CheckableLinearLayout">
    <attr name="foreground"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Here's a more minimal way to do it, using Kotlin, and without the part of being checkable :

```
class LinearLayoutEx @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    var foregroundDrawable: Drawable? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    init {
        val a = context
                .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LinearLayoutEx, defStyle, 0)
        foregroundDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.LinearLayoutEx_foreground)
        a.recycle()
    }

    override fun drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged()
        val drawable = background
        var needRedraw = false
        val myDrawableState = drawableState
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.state = myDrawableState
            needRedraw = true
        }
        if (foregroundDrawable != null) {
            foregroundDrawable!!.state = myDrawableState
            needRedraw = true
        }
        if (needRedraw)
            invalidate()
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int, oldwidth: Int, oldheight: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight)
        foregroundDrawable?.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
    }

    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
        foregroundDrawable?.draw(canvas)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && e.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            foregroundDrawable?.setHotspot(e.x, e.y)
        return super.onTouchEvent(e)
    }

}
```

**attr.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="LinearLayoutEx" tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">
    <attr name="foreground"/>
</declare-styleable>
```