# ListView selected item highlight

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-gridview

I'm working on a `GridView` with `setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL)`. By default, rows are not getting highlighted (with the blue highlight you see on **WhatsApp** or **Gallery** apps), so I am wondering, does the Android API already takes care of highlighting the selected items and I am missing something (if so, what am I missing?)  or do I have to take care of highlighting selected rows by myself (if so, how to *highlight*, not just change the background)?

Here's my code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
gridView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty));
gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

// multiChoiceModeListener is a subclass of AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener
// with no particular code on its abstracts methods.
gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(multiChoiceModeListener);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this for your ListItem background (XML layout)

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

It's basically only a selector, you can also build yourself: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/drawable/activated_background.xml

EDIT:

Given your comment, this solves it:

`android:foreground="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` with a FrameLayout

Also related question: [How to set foreground attribute to other non FrameLayout view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787738/how-to-set-foreground-attribute-to-other-non-framelayout-view)

Comment: do you mean to the row layout itself?

Comment: yep, your row/item/entry layout

Comment: it works but since my cells are images that covers the entire cell, they background can't be seen. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the Android Gallery App as an inspiration how to do an indicator or a ImageView selection: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/master

Comment: oh didn't know it was opensourced

Comment: using `foreground` instead of `background` but **only** on `FrameLayout` solved it. I'll give you the answer cause that resource is what I was looking for. Please update your answer to specify it works on framelayout with foreground attr.