# Material ripple effect hidden by other view in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, rippledrawable

I added a ripple effect on a `ImageButton`, however it is hidden by an `ImageView` used as a background for the parent view `RelativeLayout`.

Here's the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="172dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawerBackgroundImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_background"/>

    [...]

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/drawerLogoutButton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/drawerEmailTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        style="@style/FlatButtonStyle"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logout_white_24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(there's a bunch of other views but they're irrelevant here)

I'm using an `ImageView` as the background for the `RelativeLayout` as I need to set a specific `scaleType` for the image, so I can't use the basic `android:background` property.

The ripple effect is hidden as it doesn't have a mask layer (I want it to extend out of the button's bounds) and thus uses the `ImageButton`'s parent view to be displayed. The effect is perfectly visible if I remove the `ImageView`.

Is there a way to get the ripple effect to be shown above the problematic `ImageView`?

Comment: could you check my answer below and determine if it is acceptable or not? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37757154/5601387
Thank you

Comment: Hi Santiago, sorry I didn't check your answer as I've been working on another project since then and kinda forgot about this question. I'll give it a try and get back to you as soon as I can.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

*I had exactly the same issue and solved it using this thread: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=155880*

**Issue preview:**

*Before solved:*

[image: Before]

*After solved:*

[image: After]

**Explanation:**

"Borderless buttons draw their content on the closest background. Your button might not be having background between itself and the `ImageView`, so it draws underneath the `ImageView`."

**Solution:**

"Use a transparent background (`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`) on some layout containing the button (beneath the `ImageView`). This will dictate what the maximum bounds of the ripple effect is."

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                ...>

    <!-- Your background ImageView -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawerBackgroundImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_background"
        ... />

        <!-- ... -->

    <!-- HERE, you need a container for the button with the transparent
         background. Let's say you'll use a FrameLayout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <!-- Maybe more items --> 

        <!-- Button with borderless ripple effect -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/drawerLogoutButton"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            ... />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does the job, thanks! On a side note I'd replace the root `RelativeLayout` with a `FrameLayout` as we're just displaying the child views as is

Comment: @Jukurrpa, that's right, we should avoid `RelativeLayout` because it is more inefficient. Using `FrameLayout` would be better

Comment: This resulted in a clipped ripple in my case (overflow button at top right-hand side of container). Should anyone else run into the same issue, using padding instead of margin resolved the clipped ripple.

Comment: so many questions and answers of the same problem, but this one got solved this issue.

Comment: Set the bounding FrameLayout larger than (about twice) the ImageView not to cut borderless ripple.

Comment: In addition to the parent's background I also had to set some padding on my ImageButton.

Answer (score 11):

I'm aware this is an old post but I did struggle with this quite a bit today hence I'm posting what I was finally able to figure out and maybe someone else might benefit from it. One key emphasis beforehand, please do **always RTFM**!

**1) The story**

I aimed to use the unbounded ripple effect on Tab Items and consequently have it spread all over the AppBarLayout area. I had applied `@android:color/transparent` to TabLayout as the first wrapping parent and gave AppBarLayout a background color, nevertheless the ripple was still being cut off right at the borders of TabLayout's height.

**2) The moral of the story (RTFM)**

So I run to the nest of Android knowledge: **The Documentation**, and spotted this:

> ?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless for a ripple that extends beyond the view. It will be drawn upon, and bounded by, the nearest parent of the view with a **non-null background**.

**3) The course of action**

Using Layout Inspector, I realized that `@android:color/transparent` although transparent (duh!) it actually assigns 0 as the value of the *bg* attribute of a View, but **[zero is not null](https://sureshemre.wordpress.com/2013/11/09/zero-is-not-null/)** hence the ripple gets bounded at the nearest parent.

**4) The conclusion**

With that in hand, I went and set the `android:background` property of my TabLayout to `@null` rather than transparent, and now I have a fancy little ripple spread onto the area of the AppBarLayout.

**5) Outro: **ANDROID & SO FTW!**

Props to everyone in this post who shed light on the matter in word. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

I am experiencing same issue. Only solution I have found so far is not 100% okay since ripple is masked by view (its not borderless).

The solution (workaround):
surround your ImageButton with other view and set ripple to the foreground instead of the background in your layout like this:

```
<ImageView ... /> 

<FrameLayout
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" >

    <ImageButton />
</FrameLayout>
```

I would be really glad if someone explain why the ripple is drawn behind the image. Also if you look at Google Photos app, in image detail they have transparent icons over image view with ripple. I would like to replicate this, but I am not able to make the ripple to be in foreground. Does anybody know how to put transparent imagebuttons over everything but still have the ripple?

**EDIT final solution**
here you can find exactly same question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30262315/2555805)

with great explanation what is happening. the solution is the same but on top of that it solves rectangular mask by adding

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

to your layout. now your ripple should be borderless (it worked for me). 
The layout xml could be something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false">

    <ImageView ... /> 

    <FrameLayout
        ...

        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">
       <ImageView ... />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved my issue. Just had to add those two lines to the parent and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

After wrapping ImageButton inside FrameLayout, I was getting rectangular shape on touch. Applied background with oval shape on FrameLayout and got the circular shape on touch.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Used the solutions described above and worked. Managed to avoid the wrapping FrameLayout by setting foreground as ?attr/actionBarItemBackground and background as @null.

```
 <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|end"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:foreground="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
            android:padding="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_text_icon" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:clipChildern="false"   android:clipToPadding="false"` for ALL the parent layouts

here is my solution.

```
` <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:clipChildren="false"
      android:clipToPadding="false">

      <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_magnifier" />

         ....
        `
```