# Ripple shown behind a lower sibling view

Tags: android

I have created a list item (as shown in the picture) with an `ImageView` (The beautiful Miranda Kerr) and an `ImageButton` (The trash icon) with background `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`.

[image]

Now, when I click on the trash icon, the ripple is created **behind** the `ImageView`

Naturally, I want the ripple to take place in front of the image and behind the trash icon.

Full `item.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:src="@drawable/cover"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/trash_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/translucent_trash"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem in : [Ripple behind other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948189/material-ripple-effect-hidden-by-other-view-in-layout)

You can wrapp your button by a FrameLayout with a background transparent.