# Ripple on button shows up below a view that is below the button

Tags: android

This is my XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.instantbits.rippletest.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
       android:layout_width="48dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_circle_black_24dp"
       android:id="@+id/b1"/>
   <View
       android:id="@+id/view"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:background="@color/colorAccent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b1"/>
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
       android:id="@+id/b2"
       android:layout_width="48dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_circle_black_24dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Basically I have a `View` with a background and a `ImageButton` on top of it. I also have another identical `ImageButton` without a `View` behind it. The top `ImageButton` without the `View` behind it shows the ripple just fine. The `ImageButton` with the `View` behind it only shows the end of the ripple outside the `View` with the background.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is showing the ripple as expected, just that it is not visible because of the color of the view's background. And since the bg is white outside you're able to see it

Comment: So I can't have rippled inside views that sit on top of other views if that those other views have backgrounds?

Comment: I though that just because the bg was a bright color it wasn't visible to the naked eye, I tried with white and you were right, seems the ripple is behind the `View`. No idea why this happens. Wierd.

Comment: I guess I didn't show it here but I changed my ripple color to be purple to make sure I can see it.

Comment: Hey I found this, may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948189/material-ripple-effect-hidden-by-other-view-in-layout

Comment: Yeah that kind of fixes it, thanks. Basically I put my `ImageButton` inside a `LinearLayout` that is transparent. If you want to make an answer I'll gladly mark it is answered.