# selectableItemBackgroundBorderless issue in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

`selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` is not working if ImageButton or Button is placed inside a `View` with a background, but `selectableItemBackground` still works.

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/previous_ib"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_ib" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_ib"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_ib"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_ib" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what I am trying to do. But the ripple effects are gone.
[image: selectableItemBackgroundBorderless not working in ConstraintLayout]

Comment: It's happening because the parent i.e ConstraintLayout  has a background color.

Comment: try this in you ImageButton: 

android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

Comment: @BhavikMakwana It happens event, without parent background. `"?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" ` and `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` nothing works.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948189/material-ripple-effect-hidden-by-other-view-in-layout

Comment: Seems I had a similar issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111819099 . Please consider starring it, and also try the sample project with the workaround I've written later.

Answer (score 4):

Until this issue got fixed, one solution is to use 
`android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"` that creates circular ripple effect 
and also works in constraint layout.

Answer (score 3):

I used this and it worked fine for me.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally this would be a comment, but I'm too new apparently.

Have you tried
`android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

instead of
`android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`
?

Comment: Yes, but no luck.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for a reasonable answer I'm afraid this is a known bug in `ConstraintLayout`: [selectableItemBackground shown upon clicking, while selectableItemBackgroundBorderless isn't](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111819099) as it's mentioned [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/constraint-layout/issues/50)

Please consider starring it, and also reporting there in case you find more issues.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"` in `View`. But do you really need this View which doesn't have any children views in it? 
I'd recommend replacing `View` with another `ConstraintLayout`. Just put all the `ImageButton`s in the second `ConstraintLayout` and your issue will be gone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" >


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/previous_ib"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_previous"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_ib" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_ib"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_ib"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/play_ib"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_ib" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parent view is a `ConstraintLayout` then please wrap the `ImageButton` in a `FrameLayout` like :

```
<FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/play_ib"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/play_ib"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_ib">

   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_ib"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next" />

</FrameLayout>
```

There is apparently some bug in constraint layout which causes this behaviour. You can explore more if you're curious.

Answer (score -1):

**That's because background that under view.** Try to apply `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` to any view on the clear screen.

You will see a ripple effect. In My case i was using ViewPager with fragment as page. In each page was same background color like in ViewPagerFragment. I removed background from page and them ripple effect started to work properly.

`android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` work flawles in any case that i tested.