# selectableItemBackground and other Drawables disappear when there is an ImageView behind

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

My `View` hierarchy looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            androd:id="@+id/my_image"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I set an image `Drawable` to `my_background_image`, the ripple drawable provided by `?attr/selectableItemBackground` over `my_image` disappears. It doesn't matter what image I use, the ripple is completely gone. I've also found that the background (which includes the down arrow) of any "foreground" `Spinner` also disappears.

This is very strange behaviour. Does anyone know why this is happening?

**Edit:** I'd like to add that the ripple appears as long as `src="..."` is not included in the background `ImageView` or `setImageDrawable()` is not called on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a transparent background to the `LinearLayout` solves the problem.

"Borderless buttons draw their content on the closest background. Your button might not be having background between itself and the ImageView, so it draws underneath the ImageView" from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757154/2036537)