# Selector only works on android 6

Tags: android

I have added a selector to my layout which should add a white border when the layout is pressed. It works as expected but only works on Android 6.0 and older devices are not getting highlighted. I tried adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the manifest, but that didn't make a difference.

Does anybody know why this doesn't work on older android versions?

Layout that gets highlighted

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="@drawable/selector">
```

Selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/border_white_rounded" />
```

border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/color_white" />

<corners android:radius="3dp" />
```

Comment: I believe foreground is rather new, have you checked the compat support for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `android:foreground` has existed since API 1, [it was only moved up to the `View` class in API 23 (Marshmallow, 6.0)](https://youtu.be/TIHXGwRTMWI?t=84).

From API 1 until API 23, `android:foreground` only worked on `FrameLayout`.

Here is a similar question with some solutions for supporting a foreground in earlier versions of Android: [How to set foreground attribute to other non FrameLayout view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787738/how-to-set-foreground-attribute-to-other-non-framelayout-view)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and providing a solution that works!