# Ripple effect over imageview

Tags: android, rippledrawable

To describe my problem i created small example.

I have linearlayout with imageview and textview. For linearlayout i've set ripple drawable as background. But when i click or long click on linearlayout ripple animation shows under imageview. How show animation over imageview ?

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/index" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is ripple test"
            android:textColor="#FF00FF00" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**drawable-v21/ripple.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#FFFF0000">   
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>    
</ripple>
```

**drawable/ripple.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FF000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>    
</selector>
```

**screenshot how it looks now:**
[image]

Comment: Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393684/set-ripple-effect-on-image-view

Comment: Try adding `android:background="@null"` for the `ImageView`.

Comment: brilliant! both solutions work for me.

Comment: @Ajay, can you post you answer and i will mark it like solution.

Comment: I have added the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `android:background="@null"` for the `ImageView`

Answer (score 35):

Add the ripple like this

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35753159/2736039

Comment: Min SDK for this is 23

Comment: @netpork not for FrameLayouts. For FrameLayout, foreground attribute is available at least from API 16 without problems (tested on an emulator).

Answer (score 2):

If your app needs to run on API < 23, you won't be able to use the `foreground` attribute on views other than `FrameLayout`, which means adding another [useless] level in the view tree hierarchy.

Another solution is to wrap your image with a `<ripple>`, set it as your `ImageView`'s `background`, and **use `tint` and `tintMode`** to "hide" the `src` image so the background image that has the ripple over it is visible.

```xml
<!-- In your layout file -->

<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_with_ripple"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:tint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:tintMode="src_in" />
```

```xml
<!-- drawable/image_with_ripple.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?colorControlHighlight">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />

</ripple>
```

Not only this **works on API 21+** but if your image has rounded corners – or is another type of non-rectangle shape, like a star or a heart icon – the **ripple will remain in its bounds** instead of filling the view's rectangle bounds, which gives a better look in some cases.

See [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@flawyte/android-best-way-to-add-a-ripple-to-an-imageview-a8345e499a64) for an animated GIF to see how this technique compares to using a `<FrameLayout>` or the `foreground` attribute.

Comment: That's pretty impressive.  Any idea how you would pull that off with images loaded via Picasso?

Comment: @MattMc I think you'd have to subclass `<ImageView>` so when its `src` changes, it would also automatically update its background `<ripple>` item's drawable (see `View#getBackground()`). It's probably the easiest solution to use and maintain. I haven't tested though.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve for API < 21

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favorite_season"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use these two lines as attribute in that ImageView.

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
```